# dbo.Split Is Not Working In Particular database

Tags: sql-server

In My Case `dbo.Split` is Not Working in Perticular DB

Ex:

```
Declare @ID varchar(100)
SET @ID='1,2,3,4,5'
SELECT Value FROM dbo.Split(@ID,',')
```

.....Is Working In Some DB, 
But In Some Database
getting Error:

> Invalid object name 'dbo.Split'. Why So ?

Can Any one Tell me Solution?

Comment: You need to create  your split function in the database in which you are working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check that the function named `Split` exist in your database.

The function should be present in the database where it is working.

Answer (score 2):

The `dbo.Split` function probably exists only in one database.  You can copy it over, or refer to it by three-part name:

```
select * from OtherDB.dbo.Split(@ID, '.')
```

Comment: assuming that the connected user has access to that database

Comment: But what If I want to Use Individually in Database..Insted of OtherDB.dbo.Split(@ID, '.')